# If the boundary is adjoint to the differential, what is the "coboundary" adjoint to the codifferential in the continuum?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, adjoint-operators

For a smooth manifold, Stoke's theorem says that the differential/exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}$ is adjoint to the boundary operator $\partial$, i.e.
$$\int_{\partial U} \omega = \int_{U} \mathrm{d}\omega.$$
where $\omega$ is a differential form. Given an inner product of forms (e.g. induced by a metric) $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, the codifferential $\delta$ can be defined as the adjoint of $\mathrm{d}$ with respect to the inner product,
$$\langle \mathrm{d}\alpha,\beta \rangle = \langle \alpha, \delta \beta\rangle.$$
My question is, is there a coboundary $\partial^\dagger$ such that we could write a dual version of Stoke's theorem,
$$\int_{\partial^\dagger U}\omega = \int_U \delta \omega.$$
I am wondering if there is a meaningful version of this in the continuum. Naively it seems like the answer is ``no'', but it feels like $\partial^\dagger$ ought to have some sort of meaning. One could certainly define such a thing for chains, say on a simplicial complex.

Comment: Think about dimensions for the integral to be defined.

Comment: @TedShifrin I understand that $\partial^\dagger U$ would be one dimension higher. Very roughly, it would be something like an "infinitesimal thickening" of $U$. For chains on a simplicial complex, $\partial^\dagger$ of a single 0-simplex $(i)$ would be the sum of 1-simplices $\sum_{j@i} (ji)$ which terminate at $(i)$, but such a thing doesn't seem to have any continuous analogue

Comment: Yeah, it's not that simple. If you use $\delta = \pm{\star}d{\star}\omega$, you see that you're never going to be integrating $\omega$ itself over something.